# Worker role works on simulators and fails on cloud, how to start debugging?

Tags: .net, windows, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am new to windows azure, and i have made a worker role that i tested on the simulator and works fine (it should send an email and it does), however it sends me no email if i publish it on the cloud.

I don't know what is the problem and i don't know how to debug it, i appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Completely guessing ... There could be many reasons for that:

1. Your Mail Server is hosted inside your network and thus it works when you run your code locally but not when you run it in Azure because your service in Azure can't access your SMTP server.
2. It may very well be that your network admins have configured your mail servers to prevent relaying from unknown domains.

I would recommend that you contact your network admins. They should be able to sort out this problem.